# Count number of values for field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following structure in my DB:

```
_id: Dave {
    total_cars: 2
    total_bmw: // Should be 1
    total_vw: // Should be 1
    cars: [{
        model: "BMW"
    },
    {
        model: "VW"
    }]
}
```

So basically I need to count how often a certain value is in the "model" field and need to put them into a new field "total_bmw" for example. I do now the values of "model" which I need to count in advance, since there are only 2.

My question is how this can be achieved with a mongoDB-query. How can you count the number of times a field has a certain value?

Comment: I think you'll be much better off (in terms of performance and code complexity) by pre-calculating those fields (update their values when you add/change/remove a car)

Comment: use $group to group by the fiield value along with $sum to count occurence